# Flip graph of point set

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Is the ﬂip graph of every point set in $\mathbb R^3$ connected? If not, is there a
set with an isolated node?

**Def:** For a point set $S$, the ﬂip graph of $S$ is a graph whose nodes
are the set of triangulations of $S$. Two nodes $T_1$ and $T_2$ of the ﬂip
graph are connected by an arc if one diagonal of $T_1$ can be ﬂipped to
obtain $T_2$.

Any idea would be appreciate.

These tags not available for me : flip-graph

Comment: I assume a triangulation of $S$ in this context is a set $T$ such that each element of $T$ is a three-element subset of $S$ and $\bigcup T=S$ and for $a,b\in S$ there exist either no solution or exactly two solutions of $\{a,b,x\}\in T$?

Comment: This is Unsolved Problem 13 in [*Discrete and Computational Geometry*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/DCG/), p.73.

Comment: You should state the source of your question.  See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10772/18398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P28.html) at the [Open Problems Project](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/Welcome.html) and other sources, the problem of whether the flip graph is connected is open for $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^4$, and it is not even known whether it can have an isolated point.

C.L. Lawson showed in ‘Transforming triangulations’, *Discrete Mathematics* $3(1972)$, $365$-$372$ that the flip graph in $\Bbb R^2$ is connected, and Francisco Santos showed in ‘A point configuration whose space of triangulations is disconnected’, *Journal of the American Mathematical Society*, $13(2000)$, $611$-$637$, that in $\Bbb R^5$ it need not be connected.

Comment: So, I must to googling first!
Thanks dear.

Comment: @Zia: You’re welcome.

Comment: I think you missed a word in the first sentence.

Comment: @Alex: Two, in fact; thanks!